# Issues reshaping data.frame from wide to long format

Tags: r, reshape, melt

I'm trying to reshape the below data frame into a long format, but I'm not having much luck writing the code using reshape() or melt().

```
                 pH                         SO4     
Lake  Lat   Long  1976   1977   1978  1981  1976  1977
1     58    7.2   4.59   -9999  4.48  4.63  6.5-  -9999
2     58.1  6.3   4.97   -9999  4.6   4.96  5.5-  -9999
4     58.5  7.9   4.32   4.23   4.4   4.49  4.8   6.5
5     58.6  8.9   4.97   4.74   4.98  5.21  7.4   7.6
```

I need to create a data frame where each row defines a unique
combination of lake and year, columns for each chemical variable, and an additional column with the year of the measurement.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and format your questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Show the code you tried. Describe exactly where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score -1):

the **melt()** and **cast()** are too old.

More recently, the functions **pivot_long()** and **pivot_wide()** were introduced. (This functions replace **gather()** and **spread()** which replaced **melt()** and **cast()**)

Take a look at [this](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/pivot.html)